# Draw a stretchable round bracket in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I'm trying to draw a round bracket in WPF. I'm working a Math Editor, so I'll need the bracket to be able to stretch in height as required.

Since most of my stretch text research have failed I've decided to get this accomplished by drawing an `arcsegement` within my user control, And update it's height each time the `UserControl` changes in height.

But then there's just one problem, I need each part of my bracket to be in the right thickness (I'm a little bit of a perfectionist). Like a perfect bracket.

[image: Bracket Example]

Notice some parts of the bracket are thicker than others (especially the middle), Is there a way something like that can be accomplished using `arcsegment` or do I have to put a normal bracket in a `Viewbox`, stretch it and experiment till I'm satisfied (rather not though).

Any tips/ideas would be awesome:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 `ArcSegment` to form a `PathFigure`. Here is [a tutorial](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFArcSegment_2.aspx) of combining Arc segments.

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Fill="Black">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="100,30" IsClosed="True">
                    <ArcSegment Point="100,130" Size="150 150" />
                    <ArcSegment Point="100,30" Size="100 100" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: Beautiful, could you give me a link to learn how to use an arc segement like that?...And wait, what values should I change to increase it's height?

Comment: updated with a link. The starting/ending point are set by the `StartPoint` and `Point`, the curve is set by the Size (the size of the underlying ellipse), the bigger the Size, the straighter the arc.

Comment: The bracket I draw is about 15 x 100, put it in a Viewbox of roughly the same width/height ratio. Then you can control the height of the bracket with the Viewbox.

Comment: Don't worry, I'll just keep updating the point and size programmatically, I'm into perfection :). Thanks a bunch!